# Geometric interpretation of point set topology

Tags: general-topology

For a long time I've been struggling to understand how the very minimalistic description of point set topology is related to these geometric notions that most people think about when they heart the word topology. Something like a proof that one can reconstruct a shape (whatever that means outside of $\mathbb{R}^n$) given its topology would be helpful, I suppose.

From reading around it seems that many other fields of topology use point set topology in their definitions, so it would be illuminating to understand how to 'see' the translation between the point set language and the geometric image.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/a/19259/48745

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written this up before here:

https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/3iettj/confusion_about_the_definition_of_a_topological/cufwdgm

Comment: This sounds good, but this is just a explaining how point set topology appears as an abstraction, correct? How do we reason that it actually yields the 'correct' abstraction, in that it generalizes how we want? That somehow the open sets we generate really describe the geometric meaning we have in mind in contexts besides Euclidean space?

Comment: The vast majority of topological spaces *don't* have any geometric meaning, at least any we're aware of.  I mean, there are 139 distinct topological spaces with only five points.  What does that mean geometrically?  If something isn't at least locally compact and Hausdorff it probably doesn't have any meaning in the same sense that, say, a "nice" subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ does.  OTOH there are totally different and incompatible ways of describing geometry with topology, like the Zariski topology on a variety or complex manifold.

Comment: But if you can prove a theorem for an arbitrary topological space, why add extra assumptions just for the sake of keeping your theorem from applying to a wider range of spaces that *might* include some that you don't really understand?

Comment: I guess at this point I'm not sure why I'm confused still. I still feel like when a lot of people say topology they mean something more than the collection of open sets. And I still don't really see how to get to their notion from my notion.

Comment: The reason I thought of this was due to reading about topological sorting. Here the word topological comes from the idea of the topology of a network, i.e. a graph. I want to say topology is an overloaded word, but I think I'm just missing something that ties it all together.

Comment: Graph theory is not quite topology in the modern sense of the word, but it's closely connected.  Algebraic topology can in some sense be thought of as the study of higher-dimensional generalizations of graphs, although this study is largely informed by geometric considerations more than graph-theoretic ones.  But yes, there is no especially close connection between graphs and point-set topology.